# Feature Selection with Cross-validation using scikit-learn for ANOVA Test

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I'm using scikit-learn to do feature selection. Here is my code for that

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import GenericUnivariateSelect
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_classif


scores = GenericUnivariateSelect(f_classif, 'k_best').fit(features_pd, target_pd)
```

How can I use `f_classif` is a CV manner so the results are more reliable?

Answer (score 6):

Scikit-learn has a recursive feature elimination and cross-validated selection method known as [RFECV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html). The following code is for reference and is similar to the example given [on this link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
svc = SVC(kernel="linear")
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=svc, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(labels, 50),
      scoring='precision')
rfecv.fit(features, labels)
print("Optimal number of features : %d" % rfecv.n_features_)
print rfecv.support_
features=features[:,rfecv.support_]
# Plot number of features VS. cross-validation scores
plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("Number of features selected")
plt.ylabel("Cross validation score (nb of correct classifications)")
plt.plot(range(1, len(rfecv.grid_scores_) + 1), rfecv.grid_scores_)
plt.show()
```

Sample Output :

[image: Sample output for RFECV]

Reference Links :

- [An example for Recursive Feature Elimination](http://blog.datadive.net/selecting-good-features-part-iv-stability-selection-rfe-and-everything-side-by-side/)
- [Medium article on Recursive Feature Elimination](https://medium.com/@aneesha/recursive-feature-elimination-with-scikit-learn-3a2cbdf23fb7)
- [Similar Example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-in-python-with-scikit-learn/)

**EDIT : Feature Selection with CV using ANOVA Test**

To make use of Anova test and Cross-validation, you would need to do make use of [Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline), [Select Percentile](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile) and [cross-val score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score). Based on the example given [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_anova.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-svm-anova-py) you can combine these techniques to do feature selection using CV+Annova test.